# Выдает ошибку PermissionError: [WinError 5] Отказано в доступе

Tags: python, windows-10, tesseract

```
for i,cnt in enumerate(num_contours):

    min_rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)

    if ratio_and_rotation(min_rect):

        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        plate_img = img[y:y+h,x:x+w]
        print("Number  identified number plate...")
        cv2.imshow("num plate image",plate_img)
        if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xff == ord('q'):
            pass

        if(isMaxWhite(plate_img)):
            clean_plate, rect = clean2_plate(plate_img)
            if rect:
                fg=0
                x1,y1,w1,h1 = rect
                x,y,w,h = x+x1,y+y1,w1,h1
                plate_im = Image.fromarray(clean_plate)
                text = pyt.image_to_string(plate_im, lang='eng')
                print("Number  Detected Plate Text : ",text)
```

Выдает ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kanat\Desktop\number-plate-recognition-code\main.py", line 105, in <module>
    text = pyt.image_to_string(plate_im, lang='eng')
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 409, in image_to_string
    return {
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 412, in <lambda>
    Output.STRING: lambda: run_and_get_output(*args),
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 287, in run_and_get_output
    run_tesseract(**kwargs)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 258, in run_tesseract
    raise e
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 255, in run_tesseract
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd_args, **subprocess_args())
  File "C:\python\lib\subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\python\lib\subprocess.py", line 1416, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Отказано в доступе
```

Comment: А по какому пути находится папка с tesseract?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46004859/5741205

Comment: import numpy as np
import cv2
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract as pyt


pyt.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Tesseract-OCR'

Answer (score 2):

Нашел как исправить надо было указать путь к самому файлу Тессаракт

```
pyt.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Users\kanat\AppData\Local\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
```